# get the max value of a couple for all ids of a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a beginner in sql and I wanted to know how to get for each id of two joined tables the max of a couple of integer?

what I have done so far:

```
SELECT 
  Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Rente RES] AS Rente_RES, 
  Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Montant capital constitutif] AS Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N, 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant capital constitutif] AS [ "Montant_Capital_Constitutif_N-1" ], 
  IIf(
    [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant capital constitutif] = 0, 
    0, 
    (
      [Reduced_T_Rappro_N].[Montant capital constitutif] - [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant capital constitutif]
    )/ [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant capital constitutif]
  )* 100 AS [ "Evolution capital constitutif" ], 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N].[Montant Sous Rente], 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant Sous Rente], 
  (
    IIf(
      [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant Sous Rente] = 0, 
      0, 
      (
        [Reduced_T_Rappro_N].[Montant Sous Rente] - [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant Sous Rente]
      )/ [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant Sous Rente]
    )
  )* 100 AS [ "Evolution montant sous rente" ], 
  Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Montant rente initial] AS Montant_Rente_Initial_N, 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant rente initial] AS [ "Montant_Rente_Initial_N-1" ], 
  (
    IIf(
      [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant rente initial] = 0, 
      0, 
      (
        [Reduced_T_Rappro_N].[Montant rente initial] - [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant rente initial]
      )/ [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant rente initial]
    )
  )* 100 AS [ "Evolution rente initial" ], 
  MAX(
    [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant Sous Rente] + [Reduced_T_Rappro_N].[Montant Sous Rente]
  ) AS [ "Addition" ] 
FROM 
  Reduced_T_Rappro_N 
  INNER JOIN [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1] ON (
    Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Rente RES] = [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Rente RES]
  ) 
  AND (
    Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Société] = [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Société]
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Rente RES], 
  Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Montant capital constitutif], 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant capital constitutif], 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N].[Montant Sous Rente], 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant Sous Rente], 
  Reduced_T_Rappro_N.[Montant rente initial], 
  [Reduced_T_Rappro_N - 1].[Montant rente initial];
```

The divisions in my query correspond to calculations of evolution in percentage, moreover I use MS ACCESS from where the call of methods iif

Results:

| Rente_RES | Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N | Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N-1 | Evolution capital constitutif | Montant Sous Rente | Montant Sous Rente N-1 | Evolution montant sous rente | Montant Rente Initial N | Montant Rente initial N-1 | Evolution rente initial | Addition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000002-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 200,34 | 198,35 | 1,00327703554324 | 195,61 | 195,61 | 0 | 398,69 |
| 00000002-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 200,34 | 200,34 | 0 | 195,61 | 195,61 | 0 | 400,68 |
| 00000002-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 202,34 | 198,35 | 2,0115956642299 | 195,61 | 195,61 | 0 | 400,68 |
| 00000002-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 202,34 | 200,34 | 0,998302885095338 | 195,61 | 195,61 | 0 | 402,68 |
| 00000002-03 | 25070,68 | 25070,68 | 0 | 1583,2 | 1583,2 | 0 | 1472,18 | 1472,18 | 0 | 3166,4 |
| 00000003-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1358,5 | 1340,93 | 1,31028465318845 | 1266,7 | 1266,7 | 0 | 2699,43 |
| 00000003-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1358,5 | 1358,5 | 0 | 1266,7 | 1266,7 | 0 | 2717 |

What I want:
Obtain only one result per ID (Rente RES) corresponding to the maximum of the addition between [Montant sous rente N] and [Montant sous rente N-1].

| Rente_RES | Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N | Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N-1 | Evolution capital constitutif | Montant Sous Rente | Montant Sous Rente N-1 | Evolution montant sous rente | Montant Rente Initial N | Montant Rente initial N-1 | Evolution rente initial | Addition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000002-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 202,34 | 200,34 | 0,998302885095338 | 195,61 | 195,61 | 0 | 402,68 |
| 00000002-03 | 25070,68 | 25070,68 | 0 | 1583,2 | 1583,2 | 0 | 1472,18 | 1472,18 | 0 | 3166,4 |
| 00000003-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1358,5 | 1358,5 | 0 | 1266,7 | 1266,7 | 0 | 2717 |

Comment: I've removed the tag spam. Please only tag the RDBMS/Database application you are *really* using. The use of brackets (`[]`) for delimit identifying suggests T-SQL, which would be SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT Reduced_T_Rappro_N.Rente_RES, Max(([Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N-1]+[Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N])) AS Addition
FROM Reduced_T_Rappro_N
GROUP BY Reduced_T_Rappro_N.Rente_RES;

[image: Table data]

[image: Query sql view]

[image: Query result]

Comment: I get the same result as at the beginning, i.e. several IDs with different couples. Moreover I don't understand why I removed the join?

Comment: Ypu can add the distinctrow                                                                                  
SELECT distinctrow Table1.Rente_RES, Max(([Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N-1]+[Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N])) AS Addition
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Rente_RES;

Comment: So what are the names of the two tables. Also which table has one to many relationship with the other. Remember there most be a key joining the two fields, so also state the name of the field that has the pkey and fkey.

Comment: Ok thanks, now with the distinctrow it make more sense ! My last request is, how can I had more column in the SELECT without modifying the GROUP BY wich is key here. I tried to had in both SELECT and GROUP BY more columns but I get back to the first result with multiple rows

Comment: please share table names, key relationships., any image that differs from what you have shared already that can give more light to what you want to achieve. To add more columns to the query result, add the column names to the select portion of the query.

Comment: Tables: [Reduced_T_Rappro_N-1] and [Reduced_T_Rappro_N], same schema different datas.

With your query, I have the same result as you including RENTE_RES and ADDITION.

What I want now is to be able to add more columns to this query BUT, by doing so I have to modify the GROUP BY by adding more columns, and when I do that, the result is the same as the first grid table in my first post when I post this question.

Comment: So the trick is for the new columns, don't use group by, you can use any other function, e. g min, max,first etc, but ensure the new columns come after the other columns. e.g in this  SQL i have added the column Rente_RESID, but instead of adding it to the group by section, i just added a function e.g min.                                                                               SELECT DISTINCTROW Table1.Rente_RES, Max(([Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N-1]+[Montant_Capital_Consitutif_N])) AS Addition, Min(Table1.Rente_RESID) AS MinOfRente_RESID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Rente_RES;

Comment: I'm getting the right result now, it's very smart thanks for your help!